# Simulate keypress using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input box where something is already written, where i want to focus and trigger some fake keypress A, B and C one by one as if someone is typing in that textbox
i just don't want to change the innerHTML of the textbox but i want to achieve a typing effect
Please provide a solution using JS
Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide a code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var i = 0;
var plc = 'type A B C';
var speed = 300;

a.addEventListener('focus',triGr)

function triGr(){
if(i < plc.length){
a.placeholder += plc.charAt(i);
i++;
setTimeout(triGr, speed);
}
}
```

```html
<input id="name" name="name" type="text"  placeholder="" required>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the solution but if want the same thing to initiate on a click of a button what should i do?